# Command line interpreter for Windows using node.js

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, command-line, cmd

I'm currently porting some batch files to node.js. I feel more comfortable writing in JavaScript but for simple operations like copying a file, instead of:

```
copy in.txt out.txt
```

we have to write some more words...:

```
var fs = require ("fs");
var file = fs.createReadStream ("in.txt");
var newFile = fs.createWriteStream ("out.txt");

newFile.once ("open", function (fd){
    require ("util").pump (file, newFile);
});
```

If we want to remove a directory and all its content we have to use a recursive function, so 2 simple lines in batch are equivalent to a lot of lines in node.js.

I think that node.js it's so flexible and powerful and you know that windows cmd sucks, so I'm asking here if someone knows a good unix-style command line interpreter for node.js.

Thanks.

EDIT: I've done a FileUtils library for node.js -> https://github.com/Gagle/Node-FileUtils

Comment: To me, this question reads a lot like "I want to use this hammer to drive this screw in." Why not use a shell scripting language (e.g. bash, from Cygwin) to do this?

Comment: Cygwin it's more oriented to provide an environment to compile C/C++ files in Windows and of course it can be used to write unix-style scripts. But I'm asking a specific package for node.js to ease the wokr of moving, copying, deleting, showing the content of a file/directory, creating empty files, etc. with simple commands. It could be an excellent module that so many people will use. I'm just giving ideas...

Comment: Well, you asked for a command-line interpreter, not a filesystem manipulation module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thy ShellJS: https://github.com/arturadib/shelljs

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong tools.  You would be far better off with BASH or Python.   Personally I use Python on systems at work as itis almost ideal for such efforts.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [fileutils](https://github.com/dandean/fileutils) package. It's short on documentation, but a quick skim through its [source](https://github.com/dandean/fileutils/blob/master/fileutils.js) reveals `copyFileToFile` and `copyFileIntoDir` functions, and an `rm` method that recursively removes directories.